# Magento 2.X: Locate setCouponcode($string) method

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

can someone help me Locate setCouponCode($string) method in magento2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the function under the below files.

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php
/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/Totals.php
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: then where  is this setData(self:::KEY_COUPON_CODE,$couponeCode) is located?

Comment: This will set the coupon code passed in `$couponeCode` variable in the quote through the `setCouponCode()` function.

Comment: Good one, to the point answer. +1 :)

Comment: Thank you, Shoaib. :)

Answer (score 0):

This method is located in below classes

> Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Rule\CreatedatTest.php
>
> Magento\Checkout_files\quote_with_coupon_saved.php
>
> Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Rule\CreatedatTest.php

Hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please find here

```
 vendor\magento\module-quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface.php
 vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\Cart\Totals.php
```

Comment: then where is this setData(self:::KEY_COUPON_CODE,$couponeCode) is located?

Comment: @starlord, what you are trying to do? what you need exactly,